# Solution of an ordinary differential equation of the form $f' = f (f-1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

How can I find the function $f: [0, \infty] \rightarrow [0, \infty)$, satisfying,

$f^\prime = f (f-1)   $

such that f(0) = c>0, where $f^\prime$ is the first derivative?

Comment: OK, what have you tried?

Comment: Hint: separation of variables.

Comment: It's separable it's also a Bernouilli DE

Comment: When $c=1$, then $f=1$ is the unique solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$f^\prime = f (f-1)$$
Is a separable differential equation. It's also A Bernoulli's differential equation:
$$f'+f= f^2$$
$$-\left (\dfrac 1 f \right)'+\dfrac 1 f=1$$
$$u'-u=-1$$
Then use integrating factor:
$$(ue^{-x})'=-e^{-x}$$
Inetgrate and unsibstitute $u=\dfrac 1f$.

Comment: how to continue?

Comment: I added some lines @QuantumLogarithm

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You have
$$\frac{1}{f(f-1)}\,f'=1,$$
which becomes
$$\int\frac1{f(f-1)}\,df=\int1\,dx.$$